# Connecting to local device with only external IP

Tags: networking

Having problems connecting to a device on local network. Device IP has its IP set to external IP, so I cannot connect via local IP. Problem is that external IP does not exist any more. Cannot set factory defaults to device either.
Any ideas. Regards

Comment: Voted to clise as unclear what you are asking. You may be able to salvage with an edit with more into - eg What device, how is the network set up? What do you mean by external IP does not exist any more, and what is the netmask/network settings assocuated with the non-existant IP? Does it connect via ethernet, and what kind of router?

Comment: It is a Access Control Unit. Unit was once opened to external network. Don't know why they setted external IP directly to unit rather than using port forwarding. Then ISP changed static IP and we cannot access unit any more.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure the device is connected to the same ethernet as your computer, then just change your own IP address to something that would be within the same subnet as that device.

(If you don't know what netmask was configured on the device, just try adjacent addresses; e.g. if the device had 192.0.2.123, configure your PC first as 192.0.2.122/24, then as 192.0.2.124/24, and at least one of them will work.)

Whether the address is routed on the Internet doesn't actually matter much, as long as *your local network* knows where to reach it.

Comment: It is not local IP it begins with 77.38...

Comment: Whether it's a "local IP" or not is completely irrelevant. Locally all addresses work the same way, and all can be configured on your computer or any other device. (Temporarily, of course.) So if the device was 77.38.x.y, manually configure your PC to 77.38.x.(y+1) or 77.38.x.(y-1) and it should work.

Comment: Should still work. External-facing devices still need a gateway, often provided by the ISP as the adjacent address. You may also need a /30 subnet, but I'd expect /24 to be okay, since you're on the same small network and no traffic will be routed. But you won't be able to talk to anything else at all while you're system is configured this way.